# Randomly recode the first and second instance of a value in each row?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where there two instances of a value  in each row (say the value is 34). I would like to replace one instance with 3 and the other with 4 (without replament, so if the first instance gets 4, the second instance gets 3. And visa versa.)
And I would like to do the assignments randomly (so that some rows use 3 then 4, other rows 4 then 3.)

Here's my example:

```
# sample data
df1 <- data.frame(a= c(1, 2, NA, NA),b= c(2, NA, 1, NA),c= c(NA, NA,34, 2),
                 d= c(NA, 34, NA,1),e= c(34, 34,2,34),f= c(34, 1, NA,NA),
                 g= c(NA, NA,34, NA), h= c(NA,NA, NA, 34))

> df1
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
1  1  2 NA NA 34 34 NA NA
2  2 NA NA 34 34  1 NA NA
3 NA  1 34 NA  2 NA 34 NA
4 NA NA  2  1 34 NA NA 34
```

And here is an output that fits with my goal:

```
   a  b  c  d e  f  g  h
1  1  2 NA NA 3  4 NA NA
2  2 NA NA  4 3  1 NA NA
3 NA  1  4 NA 2 NA  3 NA
4 NA NA  2  1 4 NA NA  3
```

In my attempt so far I've been able to identify the columns that hold 34 using `which()` with `apply()`

```
indexes_34 <- apply(df1, 1,  function(x) {which(x == 34)})
```

And I have randomly generated a list of vectors whose elements hold 3 and 4 or 4 and 3.

```
ord <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  ord[[i]] <- sample(c(3,4), 2)
}
```

But I am having trouble with writing code that will assign the values in each 'ord' vector to each row of 'df1' at the correct indexes.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it by using `which(..., arr.ind = TRUE)` to select 34s and replace them:

```
set.seed(123)
m <- as_tibble(which(df1 == 34, arr.ind = T))
m <- m %>%
    group_by(row) %>%
    mutate(col = sample(col), value = c(3, 4)) %>%
    ungroup()
df1[as.matrix(m[, 1:2])] <- m$value
#    a  b  c  d e  f  g  h
# 1  1  2 NA NA 3  4 NA NA
# 2  2 NA NA  3 4  1 NA NA
# 3 NA  1  3 NA 2 NA  4 NA
# 4 NA NA  2  1 4 NA NA  3
```

Answer (score 3):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` option could be:

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(pmap_dfr(across(everything()), 
                    ~ `[<-`(c(...), which(c(...) == 34), sample(c(3, 4)))))

   a  b  c  d e  f  g  h
1  1  2 NA NA 4  3 NA NA
2  2 NA NA  4 3  1 NA NA
3 NA  1  4 NA 2 NA  3 NA
4 NA NA  2  1 4 NA NA  3
```

Comment: what's this `[<-` "function" here? Never seen such a thing

Comment: @GuedesBF it's called subset assignment. Considering `x <- 1:5`, `"[<-"(x, 3:5, 13:15)` does the same thing as `x[3:5] <- 13:15`. For details see the language definition https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop over all columns and for each column create a boolean random vector that has about as many TRUE as FALSE values.
Then, you just replace the `34` for TRUE values with 3 and the rest with 4.

```
for(i in 1:dim(df1)[2]){
  rb = runif(dim(df1)[1],0,1)>.5 ## Random vector
  df1[,i][df1[,i]==34 & rb] = 3
  df1[,i][df1[,i]==34] = 4
}
```

That's all. Now you have randomly replaced the 34 with 3 and 4

EDIT: If you don't want to do it randomly but force the restraint that 3 and 4 have to alternate on each row, you can do so by looping over the rows and replacing the 34 by `c(3,4)` or `c(4,3)`, depending on chance. You'd have to have two 34 per row, however.

```
for(i in 1:dim(df1)[1]){
  if(runif(1,0,1)>0.5){replace=c(3,4)}else{replace=c(4,3)}
  df1[i,][df1[i,]==34] = replace
}
```

Comment: Agreed. If it is important to have both values, see my edit. It's the same logic but forces restraints on the rows.

Answer (score 1):

**An option with purrr**
using pmap_dfr() to do rowwise operations is usually very consistent. For every iteration, you can create a vector, then modify the selected elements in place with sample(c(3,4)).

```
df1%>%pmap_dfr(., ~{
        v1<-c(...)
        v1[v1 %in% 34]<-sample(c(3,4))
        v1})

# A tibble: 4 x 8
      a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2    NA    NA     3     4    NA    NA
2     2    NA    NA     3     4     1    NA    NA
3    NA     1     3    NA     2    NA     4    NA
4    NA    NA     2     1     3    NA    NA     4
```

**apply() could be useful here too**
Since this dataframe could be converted to a matrix without any information loss:

```
data.frame(t(apply(df1, 1, function(x) replace(x, x %in% 34, sample(c(3,4))))))

   a  b  c  d e  f  g  h
1  1  2 NA NA 3  4 NA NA
2  2 NA NA  4 3  1 NA NA
3 NA  1  4 NA 2 NA  3 NA
4 NA NA  2  1 3 NA NA  4
```

Comment: Note `sample(c(3,4), 2, replace=FALSE)` is equivalent to `sample(c(3, 4))`. Same logic with base functions: `t(apply(df1, 1, function(x){x[!is.na(x) & x==34] <- sample(c(3, 4)); x}))`.

Comment: Thanks, I was aiming to make these arguments explicit to the OP, but this does make the code cleaner. Edited as suggested

Answer (score 1):

Very loop in loop'ish but might be pretty straightforward to understand what's happening. I also tried to build on the OP's idea:

```
ord <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  ord[[i]] <- sample(c(3,4), 2)
}

mat <- ifelse(df1 != 34 | is.na(df1), 0, 1 )

for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(df1)) {
    if (mat[i, j] == 1) {
      if (sum(mat[i,], na.rm = T) == 2) {
       df1[i, j] <- ord[[i]][1]
      } else if (sum(mat[i,], na.rm = T) == 1) {
        df1[i, j] <- ord[[i]][2]
      }
      mat[i, j] <- 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Creepy (nested loops are really scary), but works.